# Commands work on terminal but not in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

The following commands work on my terminal but not in my shell script. I later found out that my terminal was /bin/tcsh. Can somebody tell me what changes I need to do for /bin/sh. Here are the commands I need to change:

```
cp source_dir/*/dir1/*.xml destination_dir/
Error in sh-> cp: cannot stat `source_dir/*/dir1/*.xml': No such file or directory

sed -i "s+${initial_name}+${final_name}+" $file_name
This one does not complain but does not work as well.
```

I am adding an example for testing. The code tends to rename the names of xml files and also the contents of xml files. For example-

- The file name crr.ya.na.aa.xml should be changed to aa.xml
- The same name inside crr.ya.na.aa.xml should also be changed from crr.ya.na.aa to aa

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create dir structure for testing
rm -rf audience
mkdir audience
mkdir audience/dir1 audience/dir2 audience/dir3
mkdir audience/dir1/ipxact audience/dir2/ipxact audience/dir3/ipxact
touch audience/dir1/ipxact/crr.ya.na.aa.xml
echo "<spirit:name>crr.ya.na.aa</spirit:name>" >   audience/dir1/ipxact/crr.ya.na.aa.xml
touch audience/dir2/ipxact/crr.ya.na.bb.xml
echo "<spirit:name>crr.ya.na.bb</spirit:name>" >   audience/dir2/ipxact/crr.ya.na.bb.xml
touch audience/dir3/ipxact/crr.ya.na.cc.xml
echo "<spirit:name>crr.ya.na.cc</spirit:name>" >   audience/dir3/ipxact/crr.ya.na.cc.xml

# Create a dir for ipxact_drop files if it does not exist
mkdir -p ipxact_drop
rm -rf ipxact_drop/*
cp audience/*/ipxact/*.xml ipxact_drop/

ls ipxact_drop/ > ipxact_drop_files.log

cat ipxact_drop_files.log | \
awk '{ split($0,a,"."); print a[length(a)-1] "." a[length(a)] }' ipxact_drop_files.log > file_names.log

cat ipxact_drop_files.log | \
awk '{ split($0,a,"."); print "mv ipxact_drop/" $0 " ipxact_drop/" a[length(a)-1] "." a[length(a)] }' ipxact_drop_files.log > command.log

chmod +x command.log
./command.log

while read line
  do
    echo ipxact_drop/$line
    initial_name=`grep -m 1 crr ipxact_drop/$line | sed -e 's/<spirit:name>//' | sed -e 's/<\/spirit:name>//' `
    final_name="${line%.*}"
    echo $initial_name
    echo $final_name
    sed -i "s+${initial_name}+${final_name}+" ipxact_drop/$line  
done < file_names.log

echo " ***** SCRIPT RUN FINISHED *****"
```

Only the sed command at the end is not working

Comment: What does the very first line of the script look like (the so-called ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line)?

Comment: Here is the first line:   #!/bin/sh -f

Comment: And if you change the `sh` to `tcsh`? How does it work (or not work) then?

Comment: Yes, I tried this easy hack. But then I get syntax errors with shell commands like : 'while read line'. Best would be to understand what I missed here

Comment: By the way, the first error have nothing to do with the shell used, but about working directories. The working directory of the script might not be what you expect it to be, and so it can't find the files or directories you list. As the error message says. This is also the reason you get syntax errors when changing to use `tcsh` in the script, because at least the second line you show uses `sh` specific functionality that I donät believe `tcsh` have.

Comment: I run the command and the script from the same terminal and same directory

Comment: And the script doesn't change directory? Without knowing the full script, what it does, what it's supposed to do, then we really can't do anything more than ***guess***. Now please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The "-f" on your shebang line means "disable filename generation" (at least, at http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html ), so that's probably the cause of your first error

Comment: By the way, is there any particular reason for using /bin/sh ?   For writing new scripts from scratch, I'd be going for later shells (eg bash, etc).

Comment: Yes, -f is the cause of first error.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I will try to use bash in future. I made a small experiment and changed shebang to #!/bin/bash. I don't get any error but the sed statement doesn't work here as well.

Comment: @racraman: Nowadays `/bin/sh` is just an alias to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @mouviviel Thanks for that - ouch, showing my age !!

Comment: @valar_m For the sed command, the "-i" is expecting an extension (used for making the backup file) - eg   sed -i .back "s/from/to/" $file

Comment: Dear All, I have added an example for testing

Comment: Thanks - but you still have not put an extension in the sed command after the -i .

Comment: Try sed -i ".back" "s+${initial_name}+${final_name}+" ipxact_drop/$line

Comment: @ racraman - After adding .back extension, I get the desirable result with the example I gave for testing where each xml file has just 1 line. But as soon I try it with a real xml with lets say 1500 lines, the sed does not work any more. The code is still printing correctly the initial_name and final_name variables. Is there any limitation of sed w.r.t file size?

Comment: Some sed implementations have limits on the length of the lines, but not really on number of lines;  I'd be very surprised if 1500 lines like your example would cause a problem.  What "does not work anymore" - what error are you getting ?   I suspect it's data related - What happens if you put the first few lines that "don't work" and put them in your small example above so you can run just them ?

Comment: By 'sed does not work anymore' I mean that the 'initial_name' is not replaced by the 'final_name'. It stays as it is. I don't get any error. The substitution is simply not done. I tried to test the above example by putting some lines before and after the text present in the example xml files. The code works in that case. I will try to come with a small example that fails :)

Comment: I would suggest to strip (a copy of) your code down to the bare minimum, to reproduce the bug with some sample data, you provide, to reproduce the behaviour. Most of the code, afaik, makes no problem, right?

Comment: @ user unkown- The code works with the sample xml file I provided. It does not with full blown xml file with 1000 lines for example.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading some other posts and understood that xml files can have problems with scripts. Here is what that worked for me upto now.

To remove cp error: replace  #!/bin/sh -f with  #!/bin/sh

To remove sed error for the test input: replace sed -i ...... with sed -i.back ....